# Rank of a design matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1  \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$
What's the easiest way to see that the rank of this matrix is $3$? Obviously the first column is redundant (columns 2 + 3 = column 1, columns 4 + 5 = column 1), so I know the rank is less than or equal to $4$. But beyond this, I'm not sure if there's an easy way to see this.

Comment: That the first column equals columns 2+3 implies that you could completely remove it and there not be any consequences to the rank.  The fact that columns 2+3 = columns 4+5 implies that there is a redundancy there as well, so at least one more can be removed.  It is clear that no other can.

Comment: Since a matrix and its transpose have the same rank, it’s sometimes easier to work with the rows instead. In this case, you can eliminate half of them immediately, so again the rank is at most $4$. You can immediately see that at least three of the remaining rows are linearly independent, but you still have to show that the fourth is redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start with the last two columns, and observe that the third column can not be constructed from these two last columns. Thus, the column rank is at least 3. Finally, you can see that ($c_i$ being column $i$) 
$$
c_4 + c_5 - c_3 = c_2
$$
thereby eliminating $c_2$. As a result, you are left with a matrix of column rank $3$.